# Stochastic intensity poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes, poisson-distribution

I am wondering if, considering  $N_t$- an $\mathcal{F}_t$  poisson process with stochastic intensity $\lambda_t$ on $(\Omega,P)$ and $\tilde{N}_t$- an $\mathcal{G}_t$ poisson process with stochastic intensity $\lambda_t$ on $(\Omega,Q)$ then can we say that $N_t$ and $\tilde{N}_t$ have the same law?

Comment: If jumps are independent, and have the same waiting time, then why would they be different processes? I mean, why does it matter what the underlying sigma algebra is as long as $\mathbb{P}(X_t\leq s)$ is the same for both, along with marginals?

Comment: @AlexR.: But the definition of a stochastic intensity random process is that $N_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted and for all predictable non negative processes C we have $$E[\int_0^T C_s dN_s]=E[\int_0^T C_s \lambda_s ds]$$ so it involves the filtration.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question. If you're asking whether their probability measures on $\Omega$ are the same then, no they won't be in general. But on $\mathbb{R}$ they would be (assuming the prior comment). In other words their laws are weakly equal to each other on $\mathbb{R}$, but not strongly on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements to be a Poisson process do depend on the filtration. Roughly speaking, to be adapted is easier when the filtration is larger, and the condition involving predictable processes is more difficult to meet since there are more predictable processes when the filtration is larger. But *all this is offtopic* to determine whether the distribution of the process is Poisson or not: (1.) one needs to be sure that the process is adapted to the filtration, to take conditional expectations, and (2.) one needs to be able to compute the joint distributions of families of random variables taken from the process. These are both guaranteed by the fact that the process is Poisson (hence adapted, which gives (1.)) with given intensity function (which gives (2.)).